# Isomorphic algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

1. Let $=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ 0 & a\end{bmatrix}| a,b \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$. Is $$ isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{R})$? Justify.

Attempt: Is it generally true that algebras are isomorphic exactly when they have the same dimension (this applies to vector spaces) - they both have dimension $4$, because I don't know how to find isomorphism. Are they even isomorphic?

Comment: Isn't dim(A)=4, because a,b∈C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are algebras of dimension 4 over $\mathbb{R}$. They are not isomorphic because $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ has 1-dimensional center consisting of scalar matrices, while $\mathcal{A}$ has 2-dimensional (over $\mathbb{R}$) center of scalar matrices.

Comment: here in the center of the algebra A are meant all elements {aI|a∈C}, where I is the identity matrix?

Comment: Yes, exactly it is.

Comment: Note that, by isomorphisms the centers corresponds.